# Lectura de archivo con longitud variable

Tags: c

Tengo un archivo con longitud variable (líneas de longitud variable) y tiene espacios en blanco. Quiero leer línea por línea para procesarla, pero no puedo detectar el fin de línea.

Leeo el archivo con esta instrucción:

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%[^\0]s",&reg_Lectura) != EOF)
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? Es en C

Answer (score 1):

Si solo vas a trabajar en sistemas GNU (linux), puedes usar `getline`

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1);

if( read != 0 )
{
  // ...
}

free(line);
```

Si no es el caso puedes ir leyendo caracter a caracter y redimensionando el buffer sobre la marcha:

```
char* readLine(FILE* fp)
{
  size_t max_size = 100;
  char* line = (char*)malloc(max_size *sizeof(char)); // Reserva inicial para 99 caracteres

  size_t index = 0;

  while(1)
  {
    char c = getc(fp);
    if( c == EOF || c == '\n' )
      break;

    line[index] = c;
    ++index;
    if( index == max_line )
      line = (char*)realloc(line,max_line+100);
  }

  line[index] ='\0'; // Finalizamos la cadena
  return line;
}
```